# Angular 16 Test case fails - was thrown in afterAll

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-jasmine, angular16

Migrated the Angualr application from 6 to 16 and the test cases failing with below errors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB90N.png)

Package.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8SYv.png)

Karma.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXD8u.png)

If we add the crypto package it giving differnt error like native is undefined and like keep on missing some prorpties.

trying to add missing package but its showing not found module "fs/prmises"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPmxt.png)

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Can you please post your error message and your code instead of images ? Thanks.

Comment: read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and error in text form.